# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniavutil in java.library.path:

Tags: javacv

I am getting the following error while adding and testing javaCV to project in intellij in ubuntu 22.04. I hava read the documentation(https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) but didn't understand what to do extactly. What I have done for adding javaCV to project is,
File -> Project Structure -> Module -> dependencies (+ add dependencies)
then selected javacpp.jar, javacv.jar, opencv.jar and ffmpeg.jar from the 'javacv-platform-1.5.7-bin' folder which I downloaded.

This is the output which I get after running a code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniavutil in java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2434)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:848)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2015)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1800)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1402)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1214)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1190)
    at org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil.<clinit>(avutil.java:14)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:488)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1269)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1214)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1190)
    at org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.avformat.Read_packet_Pointer_BytePointer_int.<clinit>(Read_packet_Pointer_BytePointer_int.java:45)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.<clinit>(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:362)
    at com.cooltrickshome.MovieToImage.convertMovietoJPG(MovieToImage.java:31)
    at com.cooltrickshome.MovieToImage.main(MovieToImage.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not find jniavutil in class, module, and library paths.
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1767)
    ... 14 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone tell the exact steps to follow to add javaCV to the project in intellij ?

Comment: Please try to add **all** the JAR files to your project as dependencies.

Comment: By adding System.loadLibrary("avutil.57") and the dylib files in jniLIbs, I think I have one step further, in mac, and it seems i have problem with building the correct dylib files: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/xxx/ffmpeg-java-samples/src/main/jniLibs/libavutil.57.dylib: dlopen(/Users/xxx/ffmpeg-java-samples/src/main/jniLibs/libavutil.57.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/xxx/ffmpeg-java-samples/src/main/jniLibs/libavutil.57.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (arm64), need (x86_64)))

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem as it failed to find the the library. I ends up build my own ffmpeg, and copying the dylib files in jniLibs, and adding a line like `System.loadLibrary("avutil.57")` in the static scope.

another way could be setting up the library path:
-Djava.library.path=/Users/xxx/ffmpeg-java-samples/src/main/jniLibs

Since you are in Ubuntu, up to this point, it should be able to fix your issue. However, for the mac, the end result the exception message changes to

> tried:'/Users/xxx/ffmpeg-java-samples/src/main/jniLibs/libavutil.57.dylib',
> but hitting to another issue: (mach-o file, but is an incompatible
> architecture (have (arm64), need (x86_64)))

I am still figuring out the ffmpeg for mac M1 chip part.

after making sure the following jar file, it seems running:

> ```
> export CLZPATH=$CLZPATH:$JARROOT/org/bytedeco/javacpp/1.5.8/javacpp-1.5.8.jar
>
> export CLZPATH=$CLZPATH:$JARROOT/org/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/4.1-1.4.4/ffmpeg-4.1-1.4.4.jar
>
> export CLZPATH=$CLZPATH:$JARROOT/org/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/4.1-1.4.4/ffmpeg-4.1-1.4.4-macosx-x86_64.jar
> ```